# How to instruct bundler to ignore the checked out branch on my local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler

So I am developing a rails app `my_app`, and simultaneously developing a rails engine `my_engine` that `my_app` mounts.

Gemfile

```
gem 'my_engine', git: https://my.repo/my_engine, branch: "development"
```

Of course, to see changes to `my_engine` inside of `my_app` live, while I develop, I have instructed bundler to use the local copy of `my_engine` I am developing instead of the git repository listed in my Gemfile.

```
$ bundle config set local.my_engine path/to/my_engine
```

This works great. Except for one little annoyance. If I am developing a new feature with a new branch checked out in `my_engine`, bundler will complain and stop every time I have to restart `my_app`:

```
Local override for my_engine at path/to/my_engine is using branch FEATURE-X but Gemfile specifies development
```

The current solution is to either change the branch in Gemfile to FEATURE-X (and back again when that branch is merged) or to temporarily checkout development in `my_engine`, start `my_app` and then checkout FEATURE-X again. This gets tiring fast.

In the same way that I have told bundler to ignore the git remote repo and use a local path, is there a way to tell bundler to ignore the checked out branch on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional I'm afraid, from the docs:

> Bundler does many checks to ensure a developer won´t work with invalid references. Particularly, we force a developer to specify a branch in the Gemfile in order to use this feature. If the branch specified in the Gemfile and the current branch in the local git repository do not match, Bundler will abort. This ensures that a developer is always working against the correct branches, and prevents accidental locking to a different branch.